# Facebook Manage copyrights without uploading video's or audio files

Tags: facebook, api, audio, video

So my friends and I are doing a project which involves copyrights and we want to manage copyrights of our songs without having to upload a video with the audio in it. So we took a look at the facebook rights manager API, but the only thing we could find was that we have to upload a video in order to be able to check if our audio and/or video matches another video. This will be a lot of work because we are talking about hundreds of video's which would make an impossible job to upload all of the video's. So our question was "Is it possible t?o whitelist video's or manage the copyrights of audio and video's on facebook without having to upload the video's first?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The only way to copyright files without uploading them to your Facebook page is to use the [Media Fingerprint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/media-fingerprint/) endpoint.**

It allows you to specify a local copy of a file, and generate a media fingerprint that you can copyright with Facebook's Rights API. [Here's a guide on doing so](https://facebookfordevelopers.github.io/docs-zh_CN/docs/graph-api/media-fingerprint-api/) from facebook.

This supports music files specifically, as well as videos.